# How to solve this problem in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want the column header to be exactly compressed in the DataGridView.So I use this

> dgv_Layers.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

But this happens And I don't want the look in the circled part. What to do?

[image]

**Creation**

```
public void CreateDataTable()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Size", typeof(string)));
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        //DataGridView Properties
        dgv_Layers.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 8F, FontStyle.Regular);
        dgv_Layers.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 7F, FontStyle.Regular);
        dgv_Layers.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dgv_Layers.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dgv_Layers.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dgv_Layers.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgv_Layers.ReadOnly = true;
        dgv_Layers.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgv_Layers.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us some of your code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MindSwipe done editing

Comment: What exactly are `dt` and `ds`?

Comment: dt = DataTable,  ds = DataSet @MindSwipe

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: winforms @MindSwipe

Comment: Why would you want all columns in `fill` mode? Try setting all columns fixed width and only one to `fill` with `dgv_Layers.Columns["size"].AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;`

Comment: As i can see that is inside groupbox. Could you please select your datagridview and see where it's boundaries are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the picture I guess the `DataGridView` is parented in a `GroupBox`.
Probably the `DataGridView` is not fitting in the `GroupBox` correct, even with the `Docked` property set to `Fill` this can happen.
Try a `BringToFront()` on the `DataGridView`, if that does not fixes your issue than you will have to open the `Document Outline Windows` in VS en move the `DataGridView` up or down.

Comment: Also try to make each column width auto-size. In case that what you are trying to do in your code above is to define the default properties for each column, you should do this before creating the columns, otherwise, each object column is created with the default factory settings, not yours. Once you create a column, you need to edit its properties separatedly, not generaly.